# Dual boot with red and white dots

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

A question please:

My desktop has a dual boot setup: Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver and Windows 7.
If I choose Ubuntu in the boot menu after power up:

the screen becomes purple
UBUNTU + its logo largely in the middle of the screen
5 red dots under UBUNTU, changing color to white one after another from left to right, this process is repeated 4 to 5 times.

Thereafter the normal logon-screen with user-name is shown, system works normally.

Any idea what this might be ?

Comment: You seems to be describing the normal "system loading" screen. The dots change color to demonstrate to you that the system is working, not crashed or frozen.

Comment: Thanks user535733 ! These dots have not been here from the start, bu as you describe the situation is normal I will leave it is it is.